# Compile Qt project for Linux on remote Windows server

Tags: remote, qt

I have a high-configuration server with Windows 7 and several workstations with different versions of Linux (Ubuntu 12.04, Debian Squeeze). I want to copy sources of project to remote server, compile it to Linux executables, copy it back to Linux machine and run it in Qt Creator under debugger. What's the simpiest way to do this?

I'm thinking of running virtual machines with Linux or coLinux to compile project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with VMs; the hassle involved in trying to get cross-compiling toolchains going will drive you nuts, and the performance overhead should be fairly minor.